# How can I create a copy of an Sybase table with data?

Tags: sap-ase

I know the statement in **oracle** which copies the structure and the data.

```
create table mytable1 as select * from mytable;
```

But how to achieve the same in **Sybase ASE**?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible using `select into`!

Check more info [HERE](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc32300.1570/html/sqlug/X89970.htm)!

Comment: This link appears to be broken.

Comment: Here's a currently working link: [Sybooks] (http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc32300.1570/html/sqlug/X89970.htm)

Answer (score 5):

In Sybase ASE 16 the syntax for copying the data and structure is

```
SELECT field1, field2 INTO NewTable FROM OldTable
```

If you want to copy only the structure use this

```
SELECT field1, field2 INTO NewTable FROM OldTable WHERE 1=0
```